# NSDecimalNumbers in Array Causing "Unrecognized Selector..." messages

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ive been playing around with obj-c for a few months now and feel comfortable with a lot of things but cant make sense of something that seems very simple. I need to be able to go from an NSString split into an array then get the NSDecimalNumbers from that array. If I try to perform any calculations, I get an "unrecognized selector sent to instance." If I simply print each decimal number everything goes smoothly. If I put the values manually into NSDecimalNumbers rather than pulling from the array that also works. The error and code are below.

> 2013-10-14 15:54:42.174 test[30829:c07] -[__NSCFString
>   decimalNumberByAdding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x75a81f0 2013-10-14 15:54:42.176 test[30829:c07] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFString decimalNumberByAdding:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x75a81f0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1c90012 0x10cde7e 0x1d1b4bd 0x1c7fbbc 0x1c7f94e 0x2075 0x10e1705 0x152c0 0x15258 0xd6021 0xd657f 0xd56e8
>   0x44cef 0x44f02 0x22d4a 0x14698 0x1bebdf9 0x1bebad0 0x1c05bf5
>   0x1c05962 0x1c36bb6 0x1c35f44 0x1c35e1b 0x1bea7e3 0x1bea668 0x11ffc
>   0x1bfd 0x1b25) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

```
-(IBAction)buttonPushed: (id) sender
{
    NSString* s = @"25.55, 109.24";
    NSArray* a = [s componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
    NSDecimalNumber* dec1 = [a objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSDecimalNumber* dec2 = [a objectAtIndex: 1];
    NSDecimalNumber* sum = [dec1 decimalNumberByAdding: dec2];
    statusText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", sum, nil];
}
```

Comment: The array elements are still NSStrings. You need to transmogrify the strings into NSDecimalNumbers first

Answer (score 4):

```
NSDecimalNumber* dec1 = [a objectAtIndex: 0];
```

doesn't give you a NSDecimalNumber object.  It gives you a string (which was created via the call to componentsSeparatedByString)

Try doing this:

```
NSDecimalNumber* dec1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: [a objectAtIndex: 0]];
```

and see if you have better luck.

Answer (score 3):

you never created a NSDecimalNumber object

```
NSArray* a = [s componentsSeparatedByString: @", "];
```

will of course create an aray of strings.

Just because you type the pointer as decimal number, doesnt make the obejct to be one

```
 NSDecimalNumber* dec1 = [a objectAtIndex: 0];
```

dec1 is still a NSString. Try

```
NSDecimalNumber* dec1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[a objectAtIndex: 0]];
NSDecimalNumber* dec2 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[a objectAtIndex: 1]];

NSDecimalNumber* sum = [dec1 decimalNumberByAdding: dec2];
statusText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", sum];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `[a objectAtIndex: 0]` that is just returning a string, that you're trying to cast to a `NSDecimalNumber`.

Instead, try using something like this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPushed: (id) sender
{
    NSString* s = @"25.55, 109.24";
    NSArray* a = [s componentsSeparatedByString: @", "];
    NSDecimalNumber* dec1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[a objectAtIndex: 0]];
    NSDecimalNumber* dec2 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[a objectAtIndex: 1]];

    NSDecimalNumber* sum = [dec1 decimalNumberByAdding: dec2];
    statusText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", sum, nil];
}
```

Also note that I'm splitting the string with ", " and not just " ", otherwise the first string will be "25.55,"

See the NSDecimalNumber documentation for the details: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDecimalNumber/decimalNumberWithString:

Comment: You can send any message to nil. it will always return nil. but not an error.